# Can I enter other Schengen countries with EU residence permit but without passport?

Tags: schengen, borders

I have some travel plans to go from Netherlands to France by car. I possess Dutch residence permit, but I am non-EU citizen. The problem is that I might need to submit my passport to get visa to another country I plan to go to later. So I have: residence permit and photocopy of my passport. Is it

1. legal to cross borders by car with this set of documents
2. what are possible fines and other repercussions if police or other authorities ask for my documents in France or Belgium?

Comment: I think the question is, if you have a dutch residence but not Schengen visa, can you still drive across the border of Netherlands to Belgium or Germany or do you need to get a Schengen visa first?

Comment: @Karen no, it is not the question. Residence permit legally gives you right to travel across Schengen area. What is not clear is that is it sufficient or you need passport with it. Dutch/EU nationals can travel with just their National ID, I think residence permit is not really an ID on its own, and non-EU folk possibly have to carry passports.

Comment: @Karen actually Gilles' explains it very well.

Comment: Apparently I can't post an answer now so I'll leave a comment here. Maybe due to the refugee influx the rules have tightened a lot. I have exactly the combination of residence permit and photocopy of my passport but Flixbus flatout rejected my trip from Germany to France. I consider this to be totally ridiculous since residence permit is also theoretically an identity document with photo. But they seem to only accept passports and strictly defined "national IDs".

Comment: Even though there's absolutely nothing on the passport that illustrates the duration of my stay. That information is on the residence permit.

Comment: @JIXiang as a commercial company Flixbus probably may demand any document that they want. I guess they want to be overly cautious so that they don't have to deal with a detained passenger. The boarding is done by a driver, a driver is not qualified to figure out your documents so they set those simple rules up.

Comment: Yeah that's a way of looking at it but at least they could have explained it better in their instructions. They simply said "ein gültiger Ausweis (Reisepass/Personalausweis & Visum)" which suggests nothing that the residence permit would not be regarded as a "Personalausweis". It's also infuriating that the driver would not listen to any reasoning and only follow the instructions blindly. The police are not going to have problems with my residence permit but they might well with my passport alone. They got it the other way round.

Comment: Anyways I guess if as @Gilles answered, legally speaking the residence permit is indeed not an "equivalent travel document" to passport, then I can do nothing about it. The regulations just feel quite absurd and Kafkasque. I didn't even think of traveling from Stuttgart to Strasbourg as an international trip at all, and now my plan is all thrown into chaos, not to mention the expenses. Anyways hopefully future travellers can be more careful after seeing this experience.

Comment: @JIXiang it is annoying indeed, but this is an overall pain in the ass. When you board an intra-Schengen plane technically your residence permit should work because it is a valid government issued ID. Basically, it is not much different from citizen ID card (which is a valid travel document). I gave up rationalizing it long ago, I always carry a passport when traveling abroad.

Comment: Yeah. This will be a lesson for me to always carry my passport for sure. Previously when I was in Chile I was actually suggested to leave my passport at home and only carry a photocopy since it would be dangerous to lose it, and I just kept this notion thinking of Schengen area as a homogeneous region. I'll be careful the next time when I cross borders.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Legally speaking, you need a valid passport or equivalent travel document to cross any border of a Schengen state, whether it's an inner or outer border of the Schengen area. I can't find a list of equivalent travel documents for France, but [the one for Italy](http://www.esteri.it/MAE/EN/Ministero/Servizi/Stranieri/IngressoSoggiornoInItalia/Passaporti_documenti.htm) only lists “exotic” alternatives — documents for refugees, for seafarers, etc. (Nationals of an EU country and a few others need only an identity card).

In practice, borders inside the Schengen area are not equipped for systematic checks and there is a high likelihood that you'll just drive through without even noticing that you've passed the border. There are (or used to be) occasional checks for drug smuggling on the road from the Netherlands to France; I doubt that it's a problem if all you can show is a driving license. It's better if you have your residence permit and a photocopy of your passport — with these documents, it would take exceptional to get into trouble.

As far as I know, there is no direct penalty for not carrying an identity document in France. (I know that for nationals; I think it's also true for non-nationals.) There is an obligation that you must be able to prove your identity upon request (technically, the request has to be justified, but in practice a police officer can always find a pretext). As a non-national, you'd also have to prove your right to be there, as otherwise you could be detained and expelled. Again, with a proof of identity such as a driving license, plus a copy of your passport and residence permit, you are very unlikely to get into trouble.

The one thing you cannot reliably do without a passport is fly. All commercial airlines require a passport (or identity card), even for Schengen internal flights. They often don't check, but if they do, they're likely to not let you board the flight if you don't have documentation that's acceptable to them.

Comment: Isn't the requirement to show an id card on flight boarding been abolished in the EU? I've recently often flown on international, but intra-schengen flights without being checked for id when checking in or boarding.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Indeed, there is no legal requirements. But airlines have their own (I think to prevent ticket resales). It's true that they don't *always* check, but when they do, they tend to be very strict.

Comment: The system hasn't been fully implemented on all German airports, but if you travel with Lufthansa e.g. from Munich on an etix, you can both check-in and deposit your luggage using automates and board through a separate automatic lane at the gate. You won't speak to a Lufthansa employee before you are greeted by the stewardess in the plane.

Comment: Checks around borders are carried out by local police, they are not migration authorities. That's what I heard about Dutch-German border. I think Dutch-Belgium border is most chilled out one in Europe, it was abolished even before Schengen.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I have seen automatic check-in booth where you need to scan your passport. What is needed in your case?

Comment: @Gilles On what is your contention that a passport is required based? Everything you wrote seems plausible and accurate in practice but does not really address the question.

Comment: @Annoyed: There are several options available. If I remember correctly, you can enter the reservation number, scan the bar code on your print-out ticket or use your Miles&More card.

Comment: @Annoyed I gave an official link for Italy. I couldn't find one for France.

Comment: @Gilles It's an information page from the Italian ministry of foreign affairs but hardly an authoritative source, given the question.

Comment: "the road from the Netherlands to France" Do you mean one of the roads between Sint Maarten and Saint-Martin or some part of the 154,000km road network of Belgium?

Comment: @DavidRicherby The latter, since the question is about driving from the Netherlands to France, which obviously refers to the mainland in the absence of any specific mention of overseas territories. Do you have a point?

Comment: Apparently I can't post an answer now so I'll leave a comment here. Maybe due to the refugee influx the rules have tightened a lot. I have exactly the combination of residence permit and photocopy of my passport but Flixbus flatout rejected my trip from Germany to France. I consider this to be totally ridiculous since residence permit is also theoretically an identity document with photo. But they seem to only accept passports and strictly defined "national IDs".

Comment: @JIXiang Transport company employees don't have the same requirements as border guards. AFAIK what you have would have been accepted by a border guard. Private companies are allowed to define their own rules for boarding their vehicles, but they must observe their own rules.

Comment: @JIXiang  [Flixbus's rules](https://global.flixbus.com/terms-and-conditions) specify that you must have “a valid government-issued photo ID (identity card, passport or similar)”. (Note: these are the English rules; if you bought your ticket in Germany/France then German/French rules would apply.) As far as I can tell you met their conditions, so they should have let you on. I recommend that you ask a question here with all the details; you may be able to recover some of your expenses.

Comment: Yeah to add insult to injury, after I went back and brought my passport this time, I was never asked to produce it again in my two subsequent Flixbus trips to and back from France. Either the first driver was deliberately being a jerk to me or he didn't understand anything. Anoher explanation is that the company told them to only look for passports since as you mentioned in the first paragraph, the residence permit isn't an "equivalent document", even though it's also a photo ID. That's Kafkasque bureaucracy at its finest. The two later drivers probably just didn't care.